# Exhausted Compute Units Google Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, virtual-machine, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

i'm planning to subs google colab pro to get better GPU memory when doing some research. But i was wondering if i exhaust my 100 compute units in the first day due to continues usage of GPU, can i still use GPU for my google colab?

If anyone know or already tried to use GPU after having 0 compute units, is it still possible to use a GPU? please kindly share your experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I understood reading here: [Google colab subscription](https://colab.research.google.com/signup?authuser=3)

> What happens if I don't have computing units? All users can access Colab resources based on availability. If you do not have computing units, you can only use Colab resources reserved for non-paying users.

So, if you finish your compute units you'll be downgraded to the free user version of Colab. In that case, you can be assigned another gpu as a free user but with the common limitations.
Another useful link to understand a little bit better about usage of computing units is the following: [What exactly is a compute unit?](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/xs62o9/what_exactly_is_a_compute_unit/).
I'll be trying the paid version in a few days for at least a month to see if it is really worth it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can I use free colab without spending my computing units so that I can save them for final training.

Comment: Not sure to understand correctly. You can use the GPU for training your model and then the CPU for the rest of your code, if you're not sure that it will last for all of your code. Can you be more specific in this?

Comment: I just want to switch between colab and colab pro versions based on my usage. Even if I use same colab free version gpu my computing units are being counted.

Answer (score 0):

My experience as a Colab Pro user (basic plan) for one month is: yes. Once your 100 compute units are gone. You will be assigned to a modest configuration. However, I can say that the availability of the T4 GPU is way better than in the free version, i.e, I have it available almost all the time that I need it. But, it is frustrating that sometimes I don't have access to it even with a paid subscription (It happened only a few times this month, and I have been using it almost every day for several hours).

One thing that didn't change for me so far is RAM and disk limits, both have been around 25GB and 200GB, respectively, with or without GPU access.

Answer (score -1):

Click on "Connect" and then "View resources", in the upper right corner of your Colab window.  Then "Want even more memory and disk space? Upgrade to Colab Pro+" will appear in the middle of the pop-up window, click on it.  Then you will be in the "Choose the Colab plan that's right for you" window.  There, on the left side of the window it will say "Pay As You Go".  There select the number of compute units you want to buy (100 or 500).

After your purchase, the compute units will be added to you Colab Pro account.

Comment: answer is not relevant.